# Azure - Self service user creation

Tags: azure

I am designing / building a solution, in order to learn Azure.

First requirement is that users should be able to register themselves, login and have a change password / forgotten passord functionality.

Is there some standard functionality that gives this? For example is it included in ASP.Net MVC2, and will that run on the current version of Azure?

If there is standard functionality for this, where will the data be stored? Is Azure SQL a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the standard asp.net MembershipProvider and RoleProviders, you can use these out the box, or created custom providers to implement this functionality using your own storage/architecture.